# Best pattern to ensure clean code when passing variable frequently within class

Tags: c#

Say I have a class with a number of methods - some private, some public.

In one of the public methods, I create a list of objects. This is then used across a number of other methods, which have simply been abstracted out to make code simpler.

So I might have:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void CreateList()
    {
        List<MyClass> MyList = new List<MyClass>();
        ... populate list

        DedupeList();
        ValidateList();
    }

    void DedupeList()
    {
        // do something using MyList
    }

    void ValidateList()
    {
        // do something using MyList
    }
}
```

I was wondering what the best approach would be in this instance.

1. Make the list created by CreateList() a class level variable;
2. Pass the list a parameter to each of the sub-methods.

Comment: Probably the latter, but depends on the usage. By making the list a class field and modifying it in the other methods you introduce threading issues. So if two callers from different threads are making lists at the same time on the same instance, you can be in for a world of hurt. On the other hand, if you have more state to persist (say in addition to the list you also need to have `bool` flags, `int` counters, etc.) then you need to pass those around to each of the methods too. But all in all, I think we might need more information.

Comment: This will be a new instance each time, so shouldn't have a problem with threading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so it depends on what you're trying to achieve and what your classes responsibility is.

If you class represents a real thing which represents part of your domain, and which has state, then your private methods act on that state and I would therefore choose the former.

So

```
public class Basket
{
  private IList<string> Contents;
  public Basket()
  {
     Contents = new Contents(); 
  }

  public void Add(string Item)
  {
     Contents.Add(Item);
  }

  public void Empty()
  {
    Contents.Clear(); 
  }
}
```

This is a trite example, but all I could think of.

If however your class doesn't represent an object with state, such as the calculator below which takes some input, acts on it, and returns it without storing anything, then the latter is better.

That said, there are other considerations, such as keeping code clean and easy to read (should be very high on your priority list), limiting the number of parameters etc being passed (any more than three is often regarded as messy). Example below of when I would elect to pass parameters.

```
public class InvestmentCalculator
{
    pubilc IEnumerable<Stock> CalculateInvestmentValue(IEnumerable<Stock> Stocks)
    {
       foreach (var stock in stocks)
       {
          var itemValue = GetSotckValueFromMarket(stock);
          stock.UpdateValue(itemValue)
          AddProjection(stock);
       }
    }

    public decimal GetStockValueFromMarket(Stock stock)
    {
      //Do something
    } 

    public decimal AddProjection(Stock stock) 
    {
      //Do something    
    }

}
```

I hope that this helps

Comment: Good example - if I can understand it anyone can

Comment: In typical fashion though, my requirement falls between the 2 examples - first methods creates list, methods 2 and 3 change it and 4 uses it to produce output.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on meaning of the list. You have to find some answers. Should it be a part of the class or just a temporary variable that should live just along the method call? Is it a part of behavior of the class? How about threading? Even you may rethink if `DedupeList` and `ValidateList` methods have to be part of this class or do they deserve a separate class?

I recommend you to read "Implementation Patterns" by Kent Beck and "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin. There are dozens of very helpful tips for these kind of little but frequent cases.

Comment: The list - a List<MyClass>() will need to live throughout each of the method calls. Although publicly only a call is made to CreateList(), DeDupeList and ValidateList() will be class each time.

Comment: The book looks great but doesn't provide an answer in the sort term.